# How to modify an special aspect of css styled content without overwriting it global?

Tags: html, markup, html-lists, typo3, typoscript

I have two markers. *Content* and *Article* - both take use of CSC and it does work well. NOW I want to use a `<li>` tag instead of a `<div class="csc-header">` tag in the *Content* subpart marker. How do I modify it **without** the need to change the WHOLE css styled content for ALL subpart markers?

Comment: Please be more specific and post the code or HTML that you're referring to. You're question is far too general and your tags are confusing, since they're not referenced in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are using an statement like this:

```
CONTENT_SUBPART_MARKER < styles.content.get
```

To solve your problem, you just need to understand how it works (have a look at "[TypoScript in 45 Minutes](http://wiki.typo3.org/Ts45min)" it is available in different languages).

styles.content.get is an CONTENT object. The rendering definition is set like this

```
CONTENT_SUBPART_MARKER = CONTENT
CONTENT_SUBPART_MARKER {
  table = tt_content
  ... some more stuff ...
  renderObj < tt_content
}
```

If renderObj is not defined, `renderObj < "TABLENAME"` is set by default.

So, you can now just look up via TypoScript Object-Browser, which setting you want to change (f.e. in tt_content.text...)  and add this change to your renderObj. In this example all content objects will be rendered without header:

```
CONTENT_SUBPART_MARKER = CONTENT
CONTENT_SUBPART_MARKER {
  table = tt_content
  ... some more stuff ...
  renderObj < tt_content
  renderObj.text.10 >
}
```

To get more specific help, you need to give more specific informations.